# What is the difference between "inflection" and "intonation"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, tone

And which is utilized when turning this...

> The monkey is fat.

...into a question:

> The monkey is fat?

Comment: I wonder if the linguistics.SE might have a good answer for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Intonation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_%28linguistics%29)* would be the most fitting:

> Not to be confused with [inflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) [...]
>
> In linguistics, *intonation* is variation of pitch while speaking which is not used to distinguish words. It contrasts with [tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_%28linguistics%29), in which pitch variation does distinguish words.

So when your voice rises at the end of a question, that is technically called *intonation*.

*Inflection* has two meanings: it can sometimes mean *intonation*, as [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inflection) shows:

> modulation of the voice; change in pitch or tone of voice.

However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) defines it exclusively as the form of a word, and not the sound:

> [I]nflection ... is the modification of a word to express different grammatical categories such as tense, grammatical mood, grammatical voice, aspect, person, number, gender and case. *Conjugation* is the inflection of verbs; *declension* is the inflection of nouns, adjectives and pronouns.

Since *inflection* is ambiguous and not the correct technical linguistics term, it would be better to use *intonation*, so everyone can understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 6):

Inflection can mean ‘modulation of the voice; in speaking or singing: a change in the pitch or tone of the voice’ (OED). However, linguistically an *inflection* is a word ending that indicates the role of the word in a sentence, so it’s best to avoid using it in the other sense when talking about language. *Intonation* is the contrastive use of pitch in speech. The word used to describe the linguistic use of pitch, loudness, tempo and rhythm is *prosody*.